# Javascript getters/setters on window

Tags: javascript

Why does the following throw a TypeError in firefox 21.0?

```
Object.defineProperty(window,'windowProperty',{
    get: function(){
        return 'windowProperty'
    },

    set: function(val){
        console.log('windowProperty is being set');
    },

    configurable: true,
});

var windowProperty;
```

But declaring windowProperty without using var works:

```
windowProperty;
```

Or

```
window.windowProperty;
```

This behavior is also present in spidermonkey:

```
var a=1;

Object.defineProperty(this,'a',{
    get: function(){
        return 'a';
    },
});
```

Comment: which browser are you trying in? I tried on chrome and Firefox and didn't see the TypeError.

Comment: everything works fine in IE. What is your question ?

Comment: updated, my question is not for ie but for firefox

Answer (score 2):

Writing only

```
windowProperty;
```

does not declare a variable. It just tries to return the variable content in the closest context or `undefined` if it can't be found. It's just like an assignment without a target. For example, you can also write random text without throwing an error:

```
'Hello, world !';
123456;
undefined;
```

Using var instead try to redefine a property which is already defined before in your code, so you have an error.

**EDIT**
As precised by simonzack, the browser does not always send an error when redefining a variable. For example:

```
var test; var test;
```

doesn't throw this error (even if it is a bad idea and some JS validators will warn you). <s>By defining getters and setters, however, the browser 'locks' this property (to prevent collision, for example, two different setters on the same property).</s> My bad, it's a  misinterpretation.

Is there any reason why you want to redefine your variable?

**EDIT 2**
Taking into account that the `var` declaration went before the `defineProperty`, it allows to adds precision to my explanations. Indeed, when you first use the `var` declaration, the browser set its `configurable` state to false, which prevent doing changes on its descriptor ([See link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Modifying_a_property)). So when you try to change it with the `defineProperty` function, it causes an error. An example to see better would be to wrap the code in a closure function. This way the windowProperty defined by the `var` is not the same and everything is ok.

```
(function () {
    var windowProperty;
    Object.defineProperty(...);
    //It works because the previously defined variable is in the scope of the function and thus is not the same as window.windowProperty.
})();
```

Comment: according to your logic, `var test;var test;` should throw an error, which does not.

Comment: @simonzack You're right, the second part of my answer is incomplete. That's because you defined accessors (`get` and `set`) to this property, so the browser 'locks' it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The browser actually only "locks" the property if configurable is set to false. Check the mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty. What has this got to do with "var"?

Comment: I did not say "lock" in this way. With having set configurable to true you can indeed replace the get&set properties or delete this property, but you can't defining it again while it's here. Anyway, why would you want to do this ? I don't understand the use of `var windowProperty;`

Comment: I do it because in this case I am uncertain why in this case it behaves differently to `window.windowProperty`. And your answer has not addressed what "redefine" means for getters/setters. Can you give me a reference to the docs? I can't find any. By the way, `var windowProperty` actually runs before `defineProperty`, I don't think that you are aware of this.

Comment: There is also no reason that I can see where a getter/setter cannot be defined on an existing var, with configurable being false.

Comment: No, I didn't know `var` were before `defineProperty` (The code in your question is upside down, could you update to avoid confusion ?).
Taking that in account, I think your problem is initializing your property automatically set its `configurable` to `false` (default) and thus you can't change it: http://tinyurl.com/n4jxyd4
The reason for not overriding getters and setters when configurable is set to false is given in the link you gave before: http://tinyurl.com/kuumtk9 .

Comment: No that's false. Test it out yourself.

Comment: What should I test ? The getter/setter modification when `configurable` is `false` ? I don't know how browsers implement it but that's how it _SHOULD_ work (as said on the MDN article and specifically their configurable attribute example).

Comment: Yes of course that's how it should work, and yes I'm asking you to test what you claim: "I think your problem is initializing your property automatically set its configurable to false", which is unfortunately not true.

Comment: When testing on chrome I get this:
`var windowProperty;`  
`// undefined`  
`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, 'windowProperty');`  
`// Object {value: undefined, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: false}`  
So it seems configurable is set to false by default. (Don't know how to proper format my comment sorry)

Comment: No that's not what I'm saying. When you add `configurable: true` the code still does not work.

Comment: I don't understand. When do you add `configurable: true`. That's in the var that it set `configurable` to `false` implicitely so after a var (not in a function) you can't modify the descriptor (except writable) with `defineProperty`.